# Что должно быть залито на прод, а что нет?

Tags: оптимизация-сайтов

Есть сайт, который хостится на gh-pages. Есть папка public с такой структурой [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Сама структура проекта такова [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Что еще должно быть в папке public? Что еще должно быть на сервере? Понятно, что .idea и node_modules не надо заливать, а чего еще не должно быть сервере?

Comment: Должно быть залито то, что необходимо для работы сайта. Что необходимо для работы сайта — зависит от сайта. Изучите код сайта или спросите у того, кто делал сайт, например.

Comment: Перепишите данные с изображений в сообщение.